# How does Win32 API PeekMessage function work

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, message-loop, peekmessage

I was trying to program with Win32 API, but I came across an unusual behaviour that I wasn't expecting which left me kinda confused. In my while loop:

```cpp
while (IsWindow(hwnd)) {
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg); DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    OutputDebugStringA("loop continues\n");
}
```

and only when I am not moving the window everything works as expected, but when I try to move the window by move dragging the title bar the loop doesn't continue for some reason. I thought that is happening because I am trying to it `PeekMessage` with `while` loop but the same behaviour shows even with an `if` statement.

I would like to know what this happens and how can I make it so the rest of the loop gets executed. I don't know how the message queuing and dispatching works so I need some help.

Comment: [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493)

Comment: this may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103130/15649230

Comment: Why aren't you using a standard message loop

Comment: @DavidHeffernan i copied a similar loop from https://github.com/kevinmoran/BeginnerDirect3D11/blob/ca6e9cdd63dbc8a86e205a0f55007d565bfcbf02/02.%20Drawing%20a%20Triangle/main.cpp. And i also thought it wouldn't differ much.

Comment: @AhmedAEK also how does this code [hello triangle](https://github.com/kevinmoran/BeginnerDirect3D11/blob/ca6e9cdd63dbc8a86e205a0f55007d565bfcbf02/02.%20Drawing%20a%20Triangle/main.cpp#L276C1-L276C5) is able to keep the window updated? cause from what i just learned it shouldn't.

Comment: The other code passes `0`.  Your code passes `hwnd`.

Comment: @Eljay  iI did change it to NULL but it still gives the same behaivour so i don't really understand.

Comment: Are you writing a game?

Comment: yes, exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103130/6401656)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Not really, its just that I used d3d11 once but but my triangle didn't work as well as his did i did post about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78155344/my-d3d11-render-doesnt-immediately-update-the-part-of-the-window-that-was-off-s) but someone closed it.

Comment: *how does this code hello triangle is able to keep the window updated?* It could be that the client area doesn't be erased and redrawn, which looks like updating when moving or sizing. You can check the sample with sizing. So, according to @IInspectable 's answer, it could not make it update when moving or sizing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several situations where the system spins up a modal message loop for you. This happens, for example, when entering a menu or displaying a modal dialog box.

In this case, it is the moving or sizing modal loop (see the [`WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-entersizemove) message). This is how the system is designed to work. Your message loop gets "suspended" (by a nested modal loop) until the moving or sizing operation ends.

You'd see the same behavior with a standard `GetMessage()`-based message loop. This isn't a peculiarity of `PeekMessage()`.